# Unity inspector GUI broke when I open lip sync tab

Tags: unity-game-engine

Like my title said, I add a Lip Sync(Script) component on my 3D model, when I open the Lip Sync(Script) tab and unity appear the error

```
Unexpected top level layout group! Missing GUILayout.EndScrollView/EndVertical/EndHorizontal?
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

and keep appearing.

This is how it's broke. 
[image]

As you can see, Lip Sync(Script) cover below component. I try Reimport All, re-import Lip sync,re-open, not work.

In Unity 2018.4.11f1

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you are using the new alpha or beta versions of unity that can be a problem since the UI system has changed a little. Try using 2019.1.8 :D

Comment: @Milos Romanic I forgot to said my unity version, thank for mention. I'm in unity 2018.4.11 , not in alpha or beta

Comment: Hmmmmmm, do you have the Asset Store Pro veersion or did you pirate it? In either case, what is the verision of the Lip Sync package you have?

Comment: I don't have the Asset Store Pro, I use unity personal. I get this Lip Sync package from other who buy it.  The Lip Sync Pro version is in 1.31. I use it for my mouth animation.

Comment: have you reported it to the lipsync developer?

Comment: The current version of Lip Sync Pro is 1.52 which is about 10 updates away from you version, so you have two choices: Update the Lip Sync Pro package version, or downgrade your unity until it works.

Comment: @BugFinder his version is way too old

Comment: The third option is disabling those *things in the editor script of that component untill it works, and if you really need that *thing, then you would have to write your own gui for that *thing (sorry for such a vague answer)

Comment: @Bugfinder nop, I have not reported yet

Comment: @Milos Romantic, I already very appreciative someone reply, I will try it

Comment: @蚵仔麵線 as Milos has pointed out your version needs either updating as it may already be fixed or you should report it to the developer

Comment: OK,thanks you guys, I update it and solve the problem. <3